# database connection design

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I have a design question that I am hoping someone can chime in with some words of wisdom.  I have two applications (let's call them parent and children).  Each parent and child have their own db instance (I really want to isolate the data).  There is one parent running in Tomcat.  The children will run in separate Tomcat instances (multiple children per container, with hopefully many instances of Tomcat).  The number of children applications are dynamic - when a customer signs up, then a new deployment is auto-dropped into an available Tomcat instance, and a new db schema is created.  When children users successfully log in, it will authenticate against the parent, who will return a User object and the database connection parameters.

I definitely want to have the parent and children in separate containers.  I am not sure I need a dedicated db per child, but it "seems" more secure. My primary concern is performance and security. My dilemma is that passing encrypted db connections parameters doesn't feel right.

Can anyone offer a good design or perhaps point me to documentation that explains some solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Best to look up on Multi-tenancy design

Here's some resources, (with security and performance discussed)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-multitenantsaas/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1201dbdesigncloud/index.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: Thank you John, that is some good reading.  Now that I know what the term is for this, I can study and work towards it.  At first blush, it looks like a single db and deployment per child is going to work.
Thank you again for the links, and if you think of any other good links, please feel free to pass them along.